# "Домик с курЯми" или "домик с кУрами"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Можно сказать: домик с курЯми? Или все же нужно говорить литературно: домик с кУрами?

Иногда нужно для смеха употребить не литературное выражение. Насколько корректно будет его употребление в художественном тексте?

Comment: Скажите, а что такое "домик с курями"? Это какой-то устойчивый оборот или словосочетание с прямым значением?

Comment: В данном случае это словосочетание с прямым значением.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сказать что угодно, однако стоит понимать, будет это уместно или нет. Так, если в шуточной ситуации, в непринужденной речи сказать "домик с кур**я**ми", это, скорее всего, будет восприниматься как вполне нормальное выражение (т. е. говорящий пытается стилизовать речь под народную). В литературном языке возможность употребления такого словосочетания ограничивается, пожалуй, той же стилизацией; во всех остальных случаях это будет считаться ошибкой.

Answer (score 0):

**кУра**
**1.** *прост. рег. то же, что курица*; крупная домашняя птица.
*И в это время она сравнивала себя **с курами**, которые тоже всю ночь не спят и испытывают беспокойство, когда в курятнике нет петуха.*
 А. П. Чехов, «Душечка», 1899 г.
**2**. *прост. то же, что курятина*; мясо курицы как пища или продукт.
*В другой день ― кура в сметане: отымаешь ногу ― шкурка белая, с голубизной, а мясо под ей розовое, будто светится изнутри, ― и в сметану ее, в сметану.*
 Сергей Бабаян, «Ротмистр Неженцев», 1996 г.

Правильно будет: домик с **кУрами**.

Приведу примеры художественных (и не очень) текстов:

**Не моя эта тема с курями...**
 Андрей Базилевич

*Не моя эта тема **с курями,**

Петухи не в чести у меня.

Я хочу побывать на Майями,

Обуздать вороного коня...*

**Марш гедонистов**
 Тимур Шаов

*Вон, в курятнике наш кочет,

Не поет, а вяло квохчет,

Даже **кур** уже не топчет -

Конформист, пожрать, поспать,

Завтра ж будет теплым трупом

Возлежать в кастрюле с супом,

Так что лучше б спал **с курями**,

Да учился бы летать!*

**Анекдот**
- Мы вечером ложимся спать вместе **с курями**. А вы?
- А мы нет. У нас нет **кур**.

Вам решать, как употреблять подобное: "для смеха" или "для литературы".